# What is it called when you pass a string literal to a variable, then assign data from that string to a new variable like so?

Tags: javascript

Not sure why I am having trouble finding more information on this syntax but it goes like so...

```
var str = "Hello", length = str.length;
console.log(length); //5
```

Let me go into what I am doing so the answer can be relevant. I can keep assigning like so...

```
var str = "Hello", length = str.length, lengthtwo = str.length*2;
console.log(length); //5
console.log(lengthtwo); //10
```

*This next test ended up being inaccurate, log picked up on previous global. But I will keep up for others to see.

```
(function() {var str = "Hello", length = str.length, lengthtwo = str.length*2;})();
console.log(length); //5
console.log(lengthtwo); //10
```

It looks to be creating a global variable, but you can not create a local.

Also, I get you can do...

```
var foo = 1,
    bar = 2;
```

That would create two local scope variables as the var is passed to bar as well. So if I use a similar scope test on this one I get not defined, unlike the previous test.

**UPDATE: Rookie mistake! This does exactly as foo and bar after all, but I was accessing my global variables I had declared in previous tests. So no magic here.**

Comment: I don't get the same result when I execute your last code snippet. I get a `0` (that's `window.length`) and a `lengthtwo is not defined`.

Comment: @RobHruska See my responses bellow, I now get the undefined as well, after changing local names from the already used globals in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting can be helpful. If we unroll the line that's giving the error, we see:

```
(function() {
   var str = "Hello", 
       length = str.length, 
       var lengthtwo = str.length*2;
 })();
```

That extra `var` in the middle is the problem.

You can either remove it:

```
(function() {
   var str = "Hello", 
       length = str.length, 
       lengthtwo = str.length*2;
 })();
```

or split it into its own declaration:

```
(function() {
   var str = "Hello", 
       length = str.length;
   var lengthtwo = str.length*2;
 })();
```

Answer (score 2):

put a semicolon before the var lengthtwo declaration. you have a comma there. so:

```
var str ="Hello", len = str.length; 
or
var str="hello"; var len=str.length;
```